# serialize is not working in Jquery : spring MVC

Tags: jquery, excel, spring

I have a requirement of accepting an excel sheet from user and reading that data and showing the data on the web page, I have made a form as dialogue and prompt user to upload the sheet. After user will upload the sheet, up on submit of that form the excel sheet should be sent to controller and in controller the sheet is read and it will get back to the the jsp and display the information.

for this i had written

```
<form name="upload-file-import" method ="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="dialog" style="display: none;">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="myInput"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submitfile" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

and the jQuery goes like this

```
$("#dialog").submit( function (event){
    alert("form got submitted");
    console.log("form#dialog".serialize());
    var formdata = $("form#dialog").serialize();
    alert(formdata);
});
```

the formdata value is coming as empty string and after that the server is showing error

HTTP Status 415 : The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method ().

Comment: This is a server-side error yet you're only showing your client-side code.

Comment: can you please specify what else information i can give ??